# Internet Explorer Active X Hardware Access

Tags: internet-explorer, hardware

This is quick question,

We have a client that wants an active X embedded in a webpage that can have access ( read / write ) to a COM port.

With initial tests we are able to list the ports but get an access denied when trying to read or write to them. Is there anyway to bypass this or is it a built in feature of Internet Explorer?

The control works fine when running in the IDE. but when its embedded in IE it fails

The control is build in VS2008 VB.net using IO.Ports.SerialPort to access the COM ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this question brings back some nightmares.

I think you need to adjust the permission - in .net 1.1, the console plug-in was included, but later version need to download it (try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx)  I don't have it installed, but that should give you a starting point.

Comment: You are right,

Thanks for your help!

1) add the site you want to your trusted internet sites 

2)use the .NET framework configuration 

3) right click on run time security policy, click adjust security

4) select computer or user depending on what you want

5) trusted sites and put it on full